# Roblox - How to hide chat + leaderboard

Tags: scripting, leaderboard, roblox

I know the script to do this is:

local StarterGui = game:GetService('StarterGui')

StarterGui:SetCoreGuiEnabled (Enum.CoreGuiType.Chat, false)

and

local StarterGui = game:GetService("StarterGui")

StarterGui:SetCoreGuiEnabled(0,false)

but what kind of scripts do these go in and where do I put the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Use it in a LocalScript. The wiki page clearly states:

> This item should be used with a LocalScript in order to work as expected in online mode.

*Source: http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/StarterGui/SetCoreGuiEnabled*

If you don't know where to put the scripts, you should go over the basics on the wiki: http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Intro_to_Scripting
*(It doesn't really tell you where to put LocalScripts, but on the page of LocalScript it certainly clearly does)*